# How do I set per-world permissions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, server-administration

I'm using the [PermissionsEX](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/) plugin on my Bukkit server for command permissions and I would like to make [WorldEdit](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/worldedit) avaliable to all players only on the creative plots world (created with [Multiverse](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-core/)), but avaliable to staff anywhere?

Comment: Is Bukkit even out for 1.8? (The latest version is 1.7.10), again - I could be wrong and didn't hear about the new updates...

Comment: @aytimothy Not for 1.8. Bukkit got DMCA'd. A mirror is [here](https://savebukkit.org/), though. I think it has 1.8 client compatibility, but not 1.8 block compatibility.

Comment: I know @Whaaaaaat, it tricks the 1.8 clients into thinking it is a 1.8 server, even though it only does 1.7.10 things. (That also happened for 1.6 into 1.7) | And I've been following the DMCA debacle since the start. Since that time, they haven't released a proper version for 1.8 yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

```
//mind the indentation (trailing spaces)
groups:
    mygroup:
        ...
        permissions:
            // here put the normal permissions (on all worlds)
        worlds:
            worldname: // <- this is the world name (directory name)
                permissions:
                    ...
```

Source : [Pex manual](https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx/wiki/Advanced-permissions-setup#pex-multiworld)